# Windows Form Designer not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, designer

I'm working on our little project and when I saved my work and exit on Visual Studio. I found that the designer wasn't showing up, and it's just a bunch of code, then there was this `LoginForm.Designer.cs` file. My problem is how can I make the designer show up again because I have to customize more on the UI of the project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InventoryManagementSystem
{
    public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acer\Documents\dbIMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBoxPass_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBoxPass.Checked == false)
                txtPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            else
                txtPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        }

        private void lblClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Clear();
            txtPass.Clear();
        }

        private void pictureBoxClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Exit Applicaton", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbUser WHERE username=@username AND password=@password", con);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtName.Text);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPass.Text);
                con.Open();
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + dr["fullname"].ToString() + " | ", "ACCESS GRANTED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    MainForm main = new MainForm();
                    this.Hide();
                    main.ShowDialog();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "ACCESS DENITED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code on my LoginForm.cs

I tried different solutions on YouTube and google like shift +f7 but it's still not showing up

Comment: What happens if you right-click LoginForm.cs and choose _Opne With..._? Does the Windows Form Designer show up in the list? Is it selected? Do you get an error (often times, twiddling in the .designer.cs file will break the designer

Comment: There is nothing in the code that you've shown that would break the designer. You probably need to post the actual code in `LoginForm.Designer.cs`.

Comment: Is this .NET 5+?  The _new_ WinForms designer can be problematic.

Comment: The designer is a feature of Visual Studio, not of vscode.

Comment: @HansPassant oops yeah it was visual studio sorry my bad

Comment: @Deleted yes sir it is

Comment: I've read some articles saying that Visual Studio 2022 do have some problem regarding their winForms Design @Deleted

Comment: @Flydog57 no windows form design shows up sir

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/ and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/state-of-the-windows-forms-designer-for-net-applications/.  And its problematic regardless of who owns it.

Comment: If you are using VS2022 Preview, try disabling **Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features > Use the preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer for .NET apps** "(....for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0+ apps)"

Comment: Create a new form. Does the designer work with that? If it does, consider recreating the functionality of your logon form in the new form. Unless _you really know what you are doing_, resist the temptation to muck around in the _.designer.cs_ file

Comment: As flydog57 said, you should try to recreate a form to see if it can be displayed correctly. Blind pursuit may make you waste time, your ultimate goal is to complete your own program, not to fix the compiler.

Comment: From the current information, we cannot reproduce your problem. Unless you can create a minimal implementation use case. If I can't solve it, I will report it to the development community.

Comment: It happens, sometimes (and other times more often), that the designer of a Form doesn't render the content. You usually close that *file* (in the tabbed container) and open it up again in Solution Explorer. If it doesn't solve the issue, try to clean / rebuild the Solution, see whether now you can see some errors appear (since this also has some problems). Visual Studio, sometimes, opens up a little *stoned*, you have to restart it

Answer (score 3):

FWIW: I was having this problem with one of my forms and I determined that it was because I had an additional class defined within the form. Once I moved that class into it's own file, my problem went away.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's quesiton.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: Thanks, I never would have worked that out myself!

Answer (score -1):

> My problem is how can I make the designer show up again

VS2022 is a bit buggy with the WinForm designer. Not the ideal solution but you can fix it by commenting out all the code in the Form1.cs except for :

```
public LoginForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Goto Definition of InitializeComponent() and look for all the red dots on the right margin, mainly Event += Handlers and comment these out.

Now view the form designer. Bit by bit bring back the events in the form1.designer.cs and uncomment the corresponding events in the form1.cs

**The trick is to narrow down the problem.**

Comment: Your solution basically says comment out the code and then uncomment the code. It doesn't seem to actually address the issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity these steps worked for me, The key is to narrow down the problem.

Comment: How? The OP didn't post the code that is actually causing the error.

Comment: I've encountered it before, see how I noted VS022 is buggy.

Comment: But it didn't work for you with the code that the OP posted. Because they didn't post the code causing the error.

Comment: That's right, I was giving the steps to break down and troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: So there's no way you could know if this solution would work for the OP. It was a suggestion at best. It may be a very good suggestion, but without more detail from the OP it isn't actually an answer.

Comment: Sometimes troubleshooting is as much an art as it is science. Anyway this convo isn't going anywhere, I take your point but I still think this will help out people in the future.